# Update MySQL rows using SPARK

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using PySpark, I am updating a MySQL table. The schema has a unique key constraint on multiple three fields.

My Spark job will be running three times a day, since one of the column parts of the unique key is 'date'. I am getting a unique key constraint violation error if I am running a job more than once in a day.

Is there a way from Spark where we can delete the already-existing rows and insert new ones?

I searched the web for the solution, but I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the table on the database side. My suggestion is to create a temporary table in the MySQL database and the Spark job inserts data to the temporary table with overwrite mode.

Write a MySQL update script for the table with using a temporary table. And add a job chain after the Spark job to run the MySQL update script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *df.writer* is being used, there isn't any [UPSert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) mode currently.